# Mysql cluster + php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to connect php application and MySql cluster (master - master)

```
select version(); -- 5.6.28-ndb-7.4.9-cluster-gpl
```

As I understand, I need to install [mysqlnd_ms](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php) plugin, and it will wrap mysqli extension to resolve connections. I try to do this:

```
sudo pecl install mysqlnd_ms
```

But this command fail with

```
    /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:28:33: fatal error:
 ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.h: No such file or directory
```

And actually I have no idea what should I do now. I already establish connection from my server with apache to each cluster node, it work perfectly. Should I install this plugin? If not, what should I do instead? Any suggestions appreciate.

Comment: Is MySQLnd installed? It's different to MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

Comment: Also do you need mysqlnd_ms? I would expect this is only required if you need to manage the load balancing and replication yourself. MySQL cluster should be doing that for you.

Comment: Yes, MySQLnd installed. But, as I understand, mysqlnd it's only client for php-mysql communication, not for ballance loading and cluster at all. I'm not sure that MySQL cluster will do balance loading instead of me, because I should define connection host. I can do this trick `if(rand(0, 1) == 1){connectToHostOne()}else{connectToHostTwo()}` but it look like little silly.

Comment: I expected MySQL cluster to have a single endpoint and manage the rest internally. At any rate, make sure that mysqlnd is indeed installed because your error is that it can't be found. May be worth reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little bit about single endpoint for master-master cluster implementation, and search for some kind of proxy technologies.

I found mysql-router implementation (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/router/), and  think will use it. From my opinion, I should install this application on same server with "php" application, and do connections from php to this app.

```
[routing:example_strategy]
bind_port = 7001
destinations = master1.example.com,master2.example.com,master3.example.com
mode = read-write
```

This configuration should do load balancing inside of router.